# Parent row with multiple children, RShiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am working on RShiny app and would want to have a complex data table included with parent rows having multiple children.

With the code posted at the end of this post, I created a simple data frame with data on salaries in different continents/countries/industries/roles. The RShiny app has a selectizeInput where the user can filter the data on the continent. The body of my app shows a table with the filtered data, aggregated so that the average salary for a given geography-industry-role is shown.

[screenshot of RShiny app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDNNB.png)

I created a grouped table with headers thanks to multi-level grouping in data table, as described here:
https://datatables.net/extensions/rowgroup/examples/initialisation/multipleGroups.html

Now, what I want is to be able to do is to click on each average salary to see which n values were used to calculate it. I.e. what salaries from what companies. Something that’d look like this:

[Visualization of the desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Squxp.png)

Examples that I found for *child-parent row* functionality (I believe this is what I am after) can reveal a child that is assigned to parent as one:to:one, i.e. there’s just one child row for a parent row. In my case the parent has multiple children and I struggle to find how to include them all in my table.

Any ideas on how I could achieve this?

The R Shiny code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DT) # DT is what I need to interactive tables
library(tidyverse) # includes dplyr
library(shinyBS)

ui = dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = 'Test'),
    
    dashboardSidebar(
        
        selectizeInput("continent", "choose a continent",
                       choices = unique(my_data$continent),
                       multiple = TRUE)
    ),
    
    dashboardBody(
        
        tabPanel("Data", DT::DTOutput("table1"))
        
    ) )
server = function(input, output, session) {
    
# create some data
    my_data = data.frame('id' = 1:25, 
                         'continent' = c(rep('Europe',19), rep('North America',6)), 
                         'country' = c(rep('France', 13), rep('Spain', 6), rep('USA', 6)),
                         'industry' = c(rep('IT', 8), rep('transport', 3), rep('tourism', 2), rep('IT', 3), rep('health', 3), rep('IT', 4), rep('transport', 2)),
                         'role' = c('Frontend Developer',
                                    'Frontend Developer',
                                    'Backend Developer',
                                    'Backend Developer',
                                    'Backend Developer',
                                    'Backend Developer',
                                    'Project Manager',
                                    'Business Analyst',
                                    'Supply Manager',
                                    'Logistics Manager',
                                    'Logistics Manager',
                                    'Hotel Manager',
                                    'Hotel Manager',
                                    'Frontend Developer',
                                    'Frontend Developer',
                                    'Frontend Developer',
                                    'Dentist',
                                    'Dentist',
                                    'Dentist',
                                    'Backend Developer',
                                    'Backend Developer',
                                    'Backend Developer',
                                    'Backend Developer',
                                    'Supply Manager',
                                    'Logistics Manager'
                         ),
                         'company' = c('KLS',
                                       'Bingo',
                                       'KLS',
                                       'Apple',
                                       'Google',
                                       'S.M.T',
                                       'Apple',
                                       'SOIJ Company',
                                       'HT Logistics',
                                       'T1',
                                       'Annout',
                                       'Bi Travel',
                                       'Exodus',
                                       'Silla',
                                       'Apple',
                                       'Apple',
                                       'YourCare',
                                       'State',
                                       'Kitos',
                                       'Bingo',
                                       'Jupis',
                                       'K.',
                                       'Google',
                                       'SPED',
                                       'FedEx'
                         ),
                         'salary' = runif(25, 30000, 150000) # random salary
    )
    
    filtered_data = reactive({
        my_data %>%
            filter(continent %in% input$continent) %>%
            group_by(continent, country, industry, role) %>% # grouping for aggregation of values
            mutate(mean = round(mean(salary))) %>% 
            mutate(n = length(salary)) %>% # number of records used for aggregation
            ungroup() %>% 
            select(continent, country, industry, role, mean, n) %>% 
            distinct() %>%
            arrange(continent, country, industry, role)
    })
    
    
    output$table1 = DT::renderDT({
        
        filtered_data()
        
    },
    # headers in the table:
    class = 'cell-border hover', # to make borders in table
    extensions = "RowGroup",
    options = list(paging = TRUE, autoWidth = TRUE,
                   pageLength = 20,
                   rowGroup = list(dataSrc=c(1,2,3)), # groups by the 1st, 2nd, 3rd variable in the table
                   columnDefs = list(list(targets = c(1,2,3), visible = FALSE)), escape = FALSE # don't include headers as columns in the table
    )
    
    )
       
}

# Run the application  
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

EDIT: I tried to follow the example given by @StephaneLaurent and adapt his code to work with my reactive app.

I can't get it to work though, I don't really know JavaScript so perhaps that code needs more changes for my case? For now I tried a simpler case where all children rows are the same.

My current code (returns 'Error in as.vector(x, "character") :
cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character''):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DT) # interactive tables
library(tidyverse) # includes dplyr
library(shinyBS)


my_data = data.frame('id' = 1:25, 
                     'continent' = c(rep('Europe',19), rep('North America',6)), 
                     'country' = c(rep('France', 13), rep('Spain', 6), rep('USA', 6)),
                     'industry' = c(rep('IT', 8), rep('transport', 3), rep('tourism', 2), rep('IT', 3), rep('health', 3), rep('IT', 4), rep('transport', 2)),
                     'role' = c('Frontend Developer',
                                'Frontend Developer',
                                'Backend Developer',
                                'Backend Developer',
                                'Backend Developer',
                                'Backend Developer',
                                'Project Manager',
                                'Business Analyst',
                                'Supply Manager',
                                'Logistics Manager',
                                'Logistics Manager',
                                'Hotel Manager',
                                'Hotel Manager',
                                'Frontend Developer',
                                'Frontend Developer',
                                'Frontend Developer',
                                'Dentist',
                                'Dentist',
                                'Dentist',
                                'Backend Developer',
                                'Backend Developer',
                                'Backend Developer',
                                'Backend Developer',
                                'Supply Manager',
                                'Logistics Manager'
                     ),
                     'company' = c('KLS',
                                   'Bingo',
                                   'KLS',
                                   'Apple',
                                   'Google',
                                   'S.M.T',
                                   'Apple',
                                   'SOIJ Company',
                                   'HT Logistics',
                                   'T1',
                                   'Annout',
                                   'Bi Travel',
                                   'Exodus',
                                   'Silla',
                                   'Apple',
                                   'Apple',
                                   'YourCare',
                                   'State',
                                   'Kitos',
                                   'Bingo',
                                   'Jupis',
                                   'K.',
                                   'Google',
                                   'SPED',
                                   'FedEx'
                     ),
                     'salary' = runif(25, 30000, 150000), # random salary
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 


ui = dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = 'Test'),
    
    dashboardSidebar(
        
        selectizeInput("continent", "choose a continent",
                       choices = unique(my_data$continent),
                       multiple = TRUE)
    ),
    
    dashboardBody(
        
        tabPanel("Data", DT::DTOutput("table1"))
        
    ) )

server = function(input, output, session) {
    
    # create some data
    my_data = data.frame('id' = 1:25, 
                         'continent' = c(rep('Europe',19), rep('North America',6)), 
                         'country' = c(rep('France', 13), rep('Spain', 6), rep('USA', 6)),
                         'industry' = c(rep('IT', 8), rep('transport', 3), rep('tourism', 2), rep('IT', 3), rep('health', 3), rep('IT', 4), rep('transport', 2)),
                         'role' = c('Frontend Developer',
                                    'Frontend Developer',
                                    'Backend Developer',
                                    'Backend Developer',
                                    'Backend Developer',
                                    'Backend Developer',
                                    'Project Manager',
                                    'Business Analyst',
                                    'Supply Manager',
                                    'Logistics Manager',
                                    'Logistics Manager',
                                    'Hotel Manager',
                                    'Hotel Manager',
                                    'Frontend Developer',
                                    'Frontend Developer',
                                    'Frontend Developer',
                                    'Dentist',
                                    'Dentist',
                                    'Dentist',
                                    'Backend Developer',
                                    'Backend Developer',
                                    'Backend Developer',
                                    'Backend Developer',
                                    'Supply Manager',
                                    'Logistics Manager'
                         ),
                         'company' = c('KLS',
                                       'Bingo',
                                       'KLS',
                                       'Apple',
                                       'Google',
                                       'S.M.T',
                                       'Apple',
                                       'SOIJ Company',
                                       'HT Logistics',
                                       'T1',
                                       'Annout',
                                       'Bi Travel',
                                       'Exodus',
                                       'Silla',
                                       'Apple',
                                       'Apple',
                                       'YourCare',
                                       'State',
                                       'Kitos',
                                       'Bingo',
                                       'Jupis',
                                       'K.',
                                       'Google',
                                       'SPED',
                                       'FedEx'
                         ),
                         'salary' = runif(25, 30000, 150000) # random salary
    )
    
    filtered_data = reactive({
        my_data %>%
            filter(continent %in% input$continent) %>%
            group_by(continent, country, industry, role) %>% # grouping for aggregation of values
            mutate(mean = round(mean(salary))) %>% 
            mutate(n = length(salary)) %>% # number of records used for aggregation
            ungroup() %>% 
            select(continent, country, industry, role, mean, n) %>% 
            distinct() %>%
            arrange(continent, country, industry, role)
    })
    
     #definition of function
    # nested data adds a list column to main dataframe
    # each cell of the column contains child table of corresponding row, as a list
     NestedData <- function(dat, children){
         stopifnot(length(children) == nrow(dat)) # we need a child for each row
         g <- function(d){
             if(is.data.frame(d)){
                 purrr::transpose(d) # columns become rows
             }else{
                 purrr::transpose(NestedData(d[[1]], children = d$children))
             }
         }
         subdats <- lapply(children, g) # returns a list with function g applied to children
         oplus <- ifelse(lengths(subdats), "&oplus;", "") # lenghts: returns length of each element of list
         # if length of transposed child is not zero, "&oplus' is saved to vector, empty space otherwise
         cbind(" " = oplus, dat, "_details" = I(subdats), #I: as is, not to be interpreted by R
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE) # combine oplus (expansion symbol), parent data and children
     }
    
     # my nested data
     Dat <- reactive(
         NestedData(
         dat = filtered_data(),
         children = list(rep(my_data$salary, nrow(filtered_data()))) # same thing for each row
     ))
    
     ## whether to show row names
     rowNames = FALSE
     colIdx <- as.integer(rowNames)
    
     ## the callback
     parentRows <- reactive(which(Dat()[,1] != ""))
     callback <- JS(
         sprintf("var parentRows() = [%s];", reactive(toString(parentRows()-1))),
         sprintf("var j0 = %d;", colIdx),
         "var nrows = table.rows().count();",
         "for(let i = 0; i < nrows; ++i){",
         "  var $cell = table.cell(i,j0).nodes().to$();",
         "  if(parentRows().indexOf(i) > -1){",
         "    $cell.css({cursor: 'pointer'});",
         "  }else{",
         "    $cell.removeClass('details-control');",
         "  }",
         "}",
         "",
         "// --- make the table header of the nested table --- //",
         "var formatHeader = function(d, childId){",
         "  if(d !== null){",
         "    var html = ",
         "      '<table class=\"display compact hover\" ' + ",
         "      'style=\"padding-left: 30px;\" id=\"' + childId + ",
         "      '\"><thead><tr>';",
         "    var data = d[d.length-1] || d._details;",
         "    for(let key in data[0]){",
         "      html += '<th>' + key + '</th>';",
         "    }",
         "    html += '</tr></thead></table>'",
         "    return html;",
         "  } else {",
         "    return '';",
         "  }",
         "};",
         "",
         "// --- row callback to style rows of child tables --- //",
         "var rowCallback = function(row, dat, displayNum, index){",
         "  if($(row).hasClass('odd')){",
         "    $(row).css('background-color', 'papayawhip');",
         "    $(row).hover(function(){",
         "      $(this).css('background-color', '#E6FF99');",
         "    }, function(){",
         "      $(this).css('background-color', 'papayawhip');",
         "    });",
         "  } else {",
         "    $(row).css('background-color', 'lemonchiffon');",
         "    $(row).hover(function(){",
         "      $(this).css('background-color', '#DDFF75');",
         "    }, function(){",
         "      $(this).css('background-color', 'lemonchiffon');",
         "    });",
         "  }",
         "};",
         "",
         "// --- header callback to style header of child tables --- //",
         "var headerCallback = function(thead, data, start, end, display){",
         "  $('th', thead).css({",
         "    'border-top': '3px solid indigo',",
         "    'color': 'indigo',",
         "    'background-color': '#fadadd'",
         "  });",
         "};",
         "",
         "// --- make the datatable --- //",
         "var formatDatatable = function(d, childId){",
         "  var data = d[d.length-1] || d._details;",
         "  var colNames = Object.keys(data[0]);",
         "  var columns = colNames.map(function(x){",
         "    return {data: x.replace(/\\./g, '\\\\\\.'), title: x};",
         "  });",
         "  var id = 'table#' + childId;",
         "  if(colNames.indexOf('_details') === -1){",
         "    var subtable = $(id).DataTable({",
         "      'data': data,",
         "      'columns': columns,",
         "      'autoWidth': true,",
         "      'deferRender': true,",
         "      'info': false,",
         "      'lengthChange': false,",
         "      'ordering': data.length > 1,",
         "      'order': [],",
         "      'paging': false,",
         "      'scrollX': false,",
         "      'scrollY': false,",
         "      'searching': false,",
         "      'sortClasses': false,",
         "      'rowCallback': rowCallback,",
         "      'headerCallback': headerCallback,",
         "      'columnDefs': [{targets: '_all', className: 'dt-center'}]",
         "    });",
         "  } else {",
         "    var subtable = $(id).DataTable({",
         "      'data': data,",
         "      'columns': columns,",
         "      'autoWidth': true,",
         "      'deferRender': true,",
         "      'info': false,",
         "      'lengthChange': false,",
         "      'ordering': data.length > 1,",
         "      'order': [],",
         "      'paging': false,",
         "      'scrollX': false,",
         "      'scrollY': false,",
         "      'searching': false,",
         "      'sortClasses': false,",
         "      'rowCallback': rowCallback,",
         "      'headerCallback': headerCallback,",
         "      'columnDefs': [",
         "        {targets: -1, visible: false},",
         "        {targets: 0, orderable: false, className: 'details-control'},",
         "        {targets: '_all', className: 'dt-center'}",
         "      ]",
         "    }).column(0).nodes().to$().css({cursor: 'pointer'});",
         "  }",
         "};",
         "",
         "// --- display the child table on click --- //",
         "// array to store id's of already created child tables",
         "var children = [];",
         "table.on('click', 'td.details-control', function(){",
         "  var tbl = $(this).closest('table'),",
         "      tblId = tbl.attr('id'),",
         "      td = $(this),",
         "      row = $(tbl).DataTable().row(td.closest('tr')),",
         "      rowIdx = row.index();",
         "  if(row.child.isShown()){",
         "    row.child.hide();",
         "    td.html('&oplus;');",
         "  } else {",
         "    var childId = tblId + '-child-' + rowIdx;",
         "    if(children.indexOf(childId) === -1){",
         "      // this child has not been created yet",
         "      children.push(childId);",
         "      row.child(formatHeader(row.data(), childId)).show();",
         "      td.html('&CircleMinus;');",
         "      formatDatatable(row.data(), childId, rowIdx);",
         "    }else{",
         "      // this child has already been created",
         "      row.child(true);",
         "      td.html('&CircleMinus;');",
         "    }",
         "  }",
         "});")
    


         DT::renderDT({

             Dat()},
             callback = callback, rownames = rowNames, escape = -colIdx-1,
             #class = 'cell-border hover', # to make borders in table
             extensions = "RowGroup", # to introduce row group headers
             options = list(
                 paging = FALSE,
                 searching = FALSE,
                 columnDefs = list(
                     list(
                         visible = FALSE,
                         targets = ncol(Dat())-1+colIdx
                     ),
                     list(
                         orderable = FALSE,
                         className = "details-control",
                         targets = colIdx
                     ),
                     list(
                         className = "dt-center",
                         targets = "_all"
                     ),

                     list(paging = TRUE, autoWidth = TRUE,
                          pageLength = 20,
                          rowGroup = list(dataSrc=c(1,2,3)), # groups by the 1st, 2nd, 3rd variable in the table
                          columnDefs = list(list(targets = c(1,2,3), visible = FALSE)), escape = FALSE # don't include headers as columns in the table
                 )
             )
             )

     )

} #server

# Run the application  
# Run the application  
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: See [my blog](https://laustep.github.io/stlahblog/posts/DT_childTables.html). Is it what you need?

Comment: From what I understood, your blog describes a case in which you have a predefined number of parents and children. The filtering done by the user in my app (in reality more complex than the one I showed above) means that parents and children will be changing and I can't write these tables manually. I am afraid your method won't work here.

Comment: I don't see what you mean. You can use reactive data. The JS code is not predefined for a particular case.

Comment: I have edited the question to show how I struggled to adapt the code from blog of @StephaneLaurent to my case.